# Retrievng related posts by tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `posts` table structured this way:

```
id  |  title  |  content  |  tags
```

and a `tags` table

```
id  |  name  |  description
```

I put my tags in the `posts` table this way: `3,2,5,8` where the numbers are the `tags` table's corresponding row number. Now what might me a good way to select related posts in my post by its tag(s)?

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags ? LIMIT 10
```

I'm quite bad at logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where **database normalization** comes in. Storing multiple tag ID's in a single column is not a good idea. You should probably create a new table `post_tags`, with structure `post_id | tag_id` to link multiple tags to a single post.

You can then execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN post_tags ON post_tags.post_id = posts.id
WHERE post_tags.tag_id IN(id1,id2,etc.)
```

Comment: Exactly, there will be three tables: `posts`, `tags`, and `post_tags`

Comment: could you please help me understand the last 2 lines of code?

Comment: Please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp . "SQL joins are used to query data from two or more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these tables." In this case it means that you only want to select rows from `posts` which have a matching `tag_id` in the `post_tags` table.

Comment: I forgot one thing, How do you prevent it from including the current one? Since they're related posts it should include the current post to the list of related posts.

Comment: Simply add `AND posts.id <> yourCurrentPostID` to the query shown above.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better change your db design.
Create a new table for the relation of posts and tags.

```
create table post_tags (
  post_id int,
  tag_id int
)
```

Then you could use join to select your data like:

```
SELECT 
    p.* 
FROM 
    posts p 
LEFT JOIN 
    post_tags pt ON p.id = pt.post_id 
WHERE 
    pt.tag_id IN (?,?,?)
```

Comment: What design do you suggest? I would highly appreciate it,

Comment: I forgot one thing, How do you prevent it from including the current one? Since they're related posts it should include the current post to the list of related posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags IN ( YOUR_COMMA_SEPRATED_TAG_IDS );
```

`YOUR_COMMA_SEPRATED_TAG_IDS` can be:-
1 OR 1,2,3 or anything else...